# Converter for JSF passthrough input element ("HTML5 friendly markup")

Tags: jsf, converters, jsf-2.2, passthrough-elements

I'm using a [passthrough element](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm) inside Facelet page like this:

```
<input jsf:value="#{...}"/>
```

And I'd like to attach a `Converter` to it.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the same way as when you would be using a normal JSF [`<h:inputText>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/inputText.html) component instead of plain HTML, with either the [`converter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/inputText.html) attribute

```
<input jsf:value="#{...}" jsf:converter="fooConverter" />
```

or the [`<f:converter>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/converter.html) tag.

```
<input jsf:value="#{...}">
    <f:converter converterId="fooConverter" />
</input>
```

[Table 8-4 of the Java EE 7 tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm#BABJADGH) lists which JSF component the given passthrough element will ultimately be converted to, before insertion in the JSF component tree. The [Facelets VDL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/) lists all available tags+attributes for those JSF components.

Comment: can i user <f:convertDateTime/> instead of <f:converter/>?

Comment: Of course you can. Exactly as you can with a normal `<h:inputText>` which is under the covers being used here. Moreover, nothing stops you from just trying it and learn by experience.